# What is a good strategy for laying patio pavers?

Tags: pavers, landscaping

I would like to lay several patio pavers for a new patio.  The pavers are 12" square.  The size I want to do is rectangular, and the base is flat with a slight slope away from the house.  Should I start laying the pavers in the middle, or up by the edge of the house, or some other way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you start by laying them by the house, you can line them up much easier with the edge of the house. This will eliminate the need to trim the pavers at the house (you'll probably have to cut/trim the pavers at the other end of the patio) and make that edge look much neater.